# Visual Studio shortcut for opening command prompt in current project path

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

On a keyboard shortcut, I want to be able to start the Windows command prompt with the working directory set to the current project directory selected in solution explorer (or text editor). Unfortunately, I am unable to find an appropriate keyboard shortcut in the Visual Studio settings.

Is such a thing possible inside Visual Studio? And if so, how can I set it up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure this is possible!

### Configure an external tool

You have to set up a custom external tool. For that, go to **Tools > External Tools...** and click **Add** and configure the tool like this:

[image]

### Setup the keyboard shortcut

Next, you want to bind a shortcut to that external tool. For that go to **Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard** and bind your desired shortcut to **Tools.ExternalCommand1**. Make sure you have moved the external tool to the first position in the window shown above.

### Additional Information (For **Visual Studio Code**)

To **Open New Command Prompt**  use **Ctrl+Shift+C** to perform same action
named **workbench.action.terminal.openNativeConsole**

Comment: Great answer! Just wanted to add that using `$(SolutionDir)` opened command prompt in the correct directory for me.